# Capturo qr,código de barras en un textbox,solo me acepta string cortas,error en los largos c#

Tags: c#

Formulario ACTUALIZAR

```
namespace Fujisto_proyect{
public partial class Actualizar : Form
{
   // MySqlConnection conec = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1; database=fujitsu; Uid=root; pwd=;");
   // BdComun c=new BdComun();
    Conexion c = new Conexion();

    public Actualizar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void txtCodigo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (c.PersonaRegistrada(txtCodigo.Text) > 0)
            {
                c.llenarConsulta(txtCodigo.Text, cbxNumFamilia, txtNumParte, txtCantCaja, txtCantPallet, txtNumEmpleado, txtuAlmacen, dtpHora, dtpFecha);
            }
            else { 


            }
        }
    }



    private void txtCodigo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DialogResult resul = MessageBox.Show("Seguro que quiere actualizar  el Registro?", "Eliminar Registro", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
         if (resul == DialogResult.Yes)
         {

         }
    }

    private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Actualizar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

}

CLASE CONEXION

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Fujisto_proyect
{
public class Conexion
{
    MySqlConnection cn;
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataReader dr;
    public Conexion()
    {
        try
        {
            cn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1; database=fujitsu; Uid=root; pwd=;");
            cn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("conectado");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("No se conectó a la base de  datos :" + ex.ToString());

        }

    }

    public string Insertar(string NumQr, string NumFamilia, string NumParte, int CantCaj, int CantPallet, string NumEmpleado, string fecha, string hora, string uAlmacen)
    {

        string salida = "Se inserto correctamente";
        try
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into producto (NUmQr,NumFamilia,NumParte,CantCaj,CantPallet,NumEmpleado,fecha,hora,uAlmacen) values('" + NumQr + "','" + NumFamilia + "','" + NumParte + "'," + CantCaj + "," + CantPallet + ",'" + NumEmpleado + "','" + fecha + "','" + hora + "','" + uAlmacen + "')", cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            salida = "No se  conecto " + ex.ToString();
        }
        return salida;
    }


    public int PersonaRegistrada(string NumQr)
    {
        int contador = 0;
        try
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(" select * from producto where NumQr='" + NumQr + "'", cn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                contador++;
            }
            dr.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo consultar bien :" + ex.ToString());
        }
        return contador;
    }

    public void llenarConsulta(string NumQr, ComboBox cbxNumFamilia, ComboBox cbxNumParte, TextBox txtCantCaja, TextBox txtCantPallet, TextBox txtNumEmpleado, ComboBox cbxuAlmacen, DateTimePicker dtpHora, DateTimePicker dtpFecha)
    {
        try {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from producto where NumQr="+NumQr+"",cn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.Read()){
                cbxNumFamilia.Text = dr["NumFamilia"].ToString();
                cbxNumParte.Text = dr["NumParte"].ToString();
                txtCantCaja.Text = dr["CantCaj"].ToString();
                txtCantPallet.Text = dr["CantPallet"].ToString();
                txtNumEmpleado.Text = dr["NumEmpleado"].ToString();
                cbxuAlmacen.Text = dr["uAlmacen"].ToString();
                dtpHora.Text = dr["hora"].ToString();
                dtpFecha.Text = dr["fecha"].ToString();
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo llenar los campos: "+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hola @iliana te recomiendo que te leas los sgtes temas para que puedas mejorar tu pregunta:  [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Además no solo esperes que alguien arregle tu problema sin demostrar intento de solucionarlo por tu cuenta.

Comment: Tal cual está la pregunta no se sabe realmente lo que quieres conseguir ni cual es la pregunta exacta. Por favor, si no quieres que te cierren la pregunta edítala para que la gente que quieres que te ayude pueda hacerlo.

Comment: deberias mencioans cual es el mensaje de error que recibes

Comment: Hola, soy nueva en este plataforma es por eso que puse  código  mal, gracias  por tus recomendaciones, para tu información me gusta  investigar  y hacer  las cosas  por mi cuenta y no espero que nadie  me  las resuelva y no preguntar hasta que  ya por mis propios medios  no pueda  resolverlo. Por favor  dirígete con respeto a las  personas  que en este  pos ponen sus dudas. Estoy comenzando a  programar y así  como tu quiero aclarar mis dudas. O me discriminas  por que  soy  mujer, y eres de los que piensan  que  solo los hombres  pueden programar?

Answer (score 1):

El codigo que utilizas no es correcto, deberias trabjar con entidades y parametros. Para esto defines una entidad

```
public class Producto
{
    public string NumFamilia{get;set;}
    public string NumParte{get;set;}
    public string CantCaj{get;set;}

    //otras propeidades

    public DateTime Fecha{get;set;}
}
```

Entonces en tu codigo cargas la entidad mediente la instancia

```
public Producto llenarConsulta(string NumQr)
{
    Producto prod = null;
    try 
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from producto where NumQr = ?NumQr",cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?NumQr", NumQr);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.Read())
        {
            prod = new Producto();
            prod.NumFamilia = dr["NumFamilia"].ToString();
            prod.NumParte = dr["NumParte"].ToString();
            //otras propiedades
            prod.CantCaj = dr["CantCaj"].ToString();
            prod.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fecha"]);

        }
        dr.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("No se pudo llenar los campos: "+ex.ToString());
    }

    return prod;
}
```

y lo usas

```
Conexion c = new Conexion();
Producto prod = c.llenarConsulta(txtCodigo.Text);

if(prod != null)
{
    cbxNumFamilia.Text = prod.NumFamilia;
    cbxNumParte.Text = prod.NumParte;
    txtCantCaja.Text = prod.CantCaj;
    //otros controles
    dtpFecha.Value = prodi.Fecha;
}
```

no deberias enviar los controles como parametro en el metodo que recupera los datos